# Mac Automate 'Ask for text' keeps looping

Tags: macos, loops, automator

I'm making an automate app that basically creates a folder with subfolders within it - My workflow 'asks for text' for the first folders name, then once created it prompts to 'ask for text' to name the subfolder ...

But after the dialog pops up a few seconds later the first 'ask for text' dialog prompts again - and if I don't cancel it the automate just loops until I do.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it, turns out I had a saved Workflow from when I was learning that was running as well - so it was playing the same thing twice - it wasn't actually 'looping'